# How do I call a C++ program in a Perl script?

Tags: c++, perl

I'm writing a perl script that needs to be share with a C++ program(which is already written). And i am very poor at writing C++ programs.

Could anyone suggest me how to incorporate a C++ program into a perl script? and give the input from the perl script to the C++ program?

Comment: If the C++ program is already written, why does it matter that you're poor at writing C++? You only need your *Perl* skills for this.

Comment: that is a open script .. ya i wanted to know how to incorporate C++ in perl?

Answer (score 3):

You can execute a external script from perl using

1. [Backticks operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)
2. [system function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)
3. [exec function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)
4. [Pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Inline::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/~davido/Inline-CPP-0.39/lib/Inline/CPP.pod) - Write Perl subroutines and classes in C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) with which you can provide classes from your C++ program that you want to share with Perl. You can configure which classes you want to share in some object file.