# Using Inline::CPP vs SWIG - when?

Tags: perl, swig

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11606694/632407) question i saw two different answers how to directly call functions written in C++

1. [Inline::CPP](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline::CPP) (and here are more, like Inline::C, Inline::Lua, etc..)
2. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)
3. Handmade (as daxim told - majority of modules are handwritten)

I just browsed nearly all questions in SO tagged [perl][swig] for finding answer for the next questions:

- What are the main differences using (choosing between) SWIG and Inline::CPP or Handwritten?
- When is the "good practice" - recommented to use Inline::CPP (or Inline:C) and when is recommented to use SWIG or Handwritten?

As I thinking about it, using SWIG is more universal for other uses, like asked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25268/734304) and Inline::CPP is perl-specific. But, *from the perl's point of view,* is here some (any) significant difference?

Comment: No, nearly all XS modules are hand-written (plain XS) or bootstrapped with [InlineX::C2XS](http://p3rl.org/InlineX::C2XS), a minority only generated with the help of SWIG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used SWIG, so I cannot speak directly to it.  But I'm [pretty familiar](https://github.com/daoswald/Inline-CPP.git) with [Inline::CPP](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline::CPP).

If you would like to compose C++ code that gets compiled and becomes callable from within Perl, Inline::CPP facilitates this.  So long as the C++ code doesn't change, it should only compile once.  If you base a module on Inline::CPP, the code will be compiled at module install time, so another user never really sees the first time compilation lag; it happens at install time, just before the testing phase.

Inline::CPP is not 100% free of portability isues.  The target user must have a C++ compiler that is of similar flavor to the C compiler used to build Perl, and the C++ standard libraries should be of versions that produce binary-compatible code with Perl.  Inline::CPP has about a 94% success rate with the CPAN testers.  And those last 6% almost always boil down to issues of the installation process not correctly deciphering what C++ compiler and libraries to use.  ...and of those, it usually comes down to the libraries.

Let's assume you as a module author find yourself in that 95% who have no problem getting Inline::CPP installed.  If you know that your target audience will fall into that same category, then producing a module based on Inline::CPP is simple.  You basically have to add a couple of directives (VERSION and NAME), and swap out your Makefile.PL's ExtUtils::MakeMaker call to Inline::MakeMaker (it will invoke ExtUtils::MakeMaker).  You might also want a CONFIGURE_REQUIRES directive to specify a current version of ExtUtils::MakeMaker when you create your distribution; this insures that your users have a cleaner install experience.

Now if you're creating the module for general consumption and have no idea whether your target user will fit that 94% majority who can use Inline::CPP, you might be better off removing the Inline::CPP dependency.  You might want to do this just to minimize the dependency chain anyway; it's nicer for your users.  In that case, compose your code to work with Inline::CPP, and then use InlineX::CPP2XS to convert it to a plain old XS module.  Your user will now be able to install without the process pulling Inline::CPP in first.

C++ is a large language, and Inline::CPP handles a large subset of it.  Pay attention to the typemap file to determine what sorts of parameters can be passed (and converted) automatically, and what sorts are better dealt with using "guts and API" calls.  One feature I wouldn't recommend using is automatic string conversion, as it would produce Unicode-unfriendly conversions.  Better to handle strings explicitly through API calls.

The portion of C++ that isn't handled gracefully by Inline::CPP is template metaprogramming.  You're free to use templates in your code, and free to use the STL.  However, you cannot simply pass STL type parameters and hope that Inline::CPP will know how to convert them.  It deals with POD (basic data types), not STL stuff.  Furthermore, if you compose a template-based function or object method, the C++ compiler won't know what context Perl plans to call the function in, so it won't know what type to apply to the template at compiletime.  Consequently, the functions and object methods exposed directly to Inline::CPP need to be plain functions or methods; not template functions or classes.

These limitations in practice aren't hard to deal with as long as you know what to expect.  If you want to expose a template class directly to Inline::CPP, just write a wrapper class that either inherits or composes itself of the template class, but gives it a concrete type for Inline::CPP to work with.

Inline::CPP is also useful in automatically generating function wrappers for existing C++ libraries.  The documentation explains how to do that.

One of the advantages to Inline::CPP over Swig is that if you already have some experience with [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html), [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html), and [perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html), you will feel right at home already.  With Swig, you'll have to learn the Swig way of doing things first, and then figure out how to apply that to Perl, and possibly, how to do it in a way that is CPAN-distributable.

Another advantage of using Inline::CPP is that it is a somewhat familiar tool in the Perl community.  You are going to find a lot more people who understand Perl XS, Inline::C, and to some extent Inline::CPP than you will find people who have used Swig with Perl.  Although XS can be messy, it's a road more heavily travelled than using Perl with Swig.

Inline::CPP is also a common topic on the [inline@perl.org](http://lists.perl.org/list/inline.html) mailing list.  In addition to myself, the maintainer of Inline::C and several other Inline-family maintainers frequent the list, and do our best to assist people who need a hand getting going with the Inline family of modules.

You might also find [my Perl Mongers talk on Inline::CPP](https://github.com/daoswald/Inline-C-Perl-Mongers-Talk.git) useful in exploring how it might work for you.  Additionally, [Math::Prime::FastSieve](https://metacpan.org/module/Math::Prime::FastSieve) stands as a proof-of-concept for basing a module on Inline::CPP (with an Inline::CPP dependency).  Furthermore, Rob (sisyphus), the current Inline maintainer, and author of InlineX::CPP2XS has actually included an example in the [InlineX::CPP2XS](https://metacpan.org/module/InlineX::CPP2XS) distribution that takes my Math::Prime::FastSieve and converts it to plain XS code using his InlineX::CPP2XS.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably also give [ExtUtils::XSpp](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils%3a%3aXSpp) a look. I think it requires you to declare a bit more stuff than Inline::CPP or SWIG, but it's rather powerful.